# Cannot style html5 progress bars?

Tags: css, html

Firstly I would like to mention this is for an assignment so I cannot use any alternative to the html5 progress bar unfortunately.

It seems as if any css I try on the bar has no effect other than possibly turning the bar green. Here is the code and result:

[image: Styled]

If I do not apply any styling it appears as such:

[image: Unstyled]

I must be missing something here :/

```
<style>
progress { background: blue; }
</style>

<progress id="progressBar" class="test_bar" value="185" max="185"></progress>
<span id="status"></span>
```

Comment: you really should post html and css instead of images, your question will more likely be answered that way

Comment: Please add some code so we can see what is going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this and it should help: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html5-progress-bar/. Just like with the HTML5 audio and video players, the progress bar will look different on each browser. Here's a sample from the page:

"In Firefox, the styles affect the progress bar, while the progress meter / value is not affected."

"In Chrome and Safari, it will remove the native styles and presentation from the platform and replace it with the Webkit stylesheet, the styles above will not be applied (at least, at the moment)."

"So, we need some more workaround in these cases."

Comment: CSS-Tricks has never let me down. This also shows the default look across the browsers on both windows and mac: http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2012/01/03/cross-browser-html5-progress-bars-in-depth/.